# How to resolve google play payment error?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I have been developing android app,Which has subscription enabled via in app billing.I tried to test the subscription with two gmail account, but when every time I tried to test it says that “Your payment could not be processed at this time. You may receive an email asking you to verify your account”. But I never receive any email regarding verification. I have attached the screen shot with this please someone help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: Is you app published? If not, then you have to add those accounts that you are testing with to the list of authorised accounts in the dev console

Comment: The app is been published a month ago.

Comment: But have you published the version with the IAP in it?

Comment: Sorry what you mean by IAP could u please explain bit more about IAP.

Comment: Now i am getting new error from google play (i.e) "your order cannot be processed please try again". Now i am not able to purchase any other apps from google play. Do you know something regarding this?

Comment: IAP = in app purchase, if you have not published the version of your app with the IAP in it then it won't work (at least that is what I understand from the limited time I have looked at them